# Trying to call a function but nothing happens

Tags: c++, lua

I can't seem to figure it out, and the examples I received in class appear to be quite different from Lua examples I see online.

I copied this code from class and added it to my cpp file:

```
#include "InputManager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

InputManager* InputManager::instance = NULL;

int LuaExample_OutputInt(lua_State *L) {
    int argc = lua_gettop(L);

    if (argc == 1) {
        const lua_Integer value = lua_tointeger(L, 1);
        std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
    }
    return 1;
};
REGISTER_LUA_FUNCTION(LuaExample, OutputInt)  

void InputManager::update() {

    std::string command;

    std::cout << "Enter LUA command:" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, command);

    LuaState::getLuaState()->executeLuaString(command.c_str());
}
```

The program compiles without an issue and shows no errors, but the program just ends after I input a value, it never enters the LuaExample_OutputInt section. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never interacted with C++, so I cannot help. But for future reference, Lua is spelt "Lua", not "LUA". It is not an acronym.

Comment: Maybe to can try to call `LuaExample_OutputInt()` yourself first. If nothing printed, check the value of `argc`. If it doesn't work, you need to check how `REGISTER_LUA_FUNCTION` is defined. I am not familiar with Lua, hope these can help you.

Comment: @warspyking - Thanks for pointing that out. My teacher has it as "LUA" in all his slides, but I don't think he's all that familiar with the language.

Comment: @William Chan - I can't figure out a way to call `LuaExample_OutputInt()` without causing an error... `REGISTER_LUA_FUNCTION` leads to a macro which leads to some other things... I found out it's hitting some error handling if statement, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix the issue so it runs properly. I think i'll just have to wait the days/weeks? until my teacher posts his working program and figure it out from there, and try to find an alternate (non-Lua) solution for what I'm working on now.

Comment: @user Glad I was able to correct you. Don't forget to tell your teacher!

Comment: AFAIK `REGISTER_LUA_FUNCTION`, the `LuaState` class, etc. are not part of a standard library. Is that part of a library you were given from the course? Also from the fragment I'd expect it expects you to type a Lua statement, not a value.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without knowing what REGISTER_LUA_FUNCTION does we can't reproduce your problem.